# unable to add a icon to a new custom RTE plugin in aem

Tags: aem

A new plugin has been added into Existing plugin list and  this newly added plugin icon is not defined , so how to add a icon to this new plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed example for adding custom plugin to RTE toolbar - https://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2021/03/aem-cloud-service-css-and-color-picker-plugin-rte-rich-text-editor.html.

This line adds the icon for new plugin:

`tbGenerator.registerIcon(groupFeature, "colorPalette");`

Point is, we are reusing coral icons from library. List of icons are defined [here](https://www.adobe.io/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/coral-ui/coralui3/Coral.Icon.html). This is easier also to reuse coral icons instead of defining new.